# Django - Same page record 2 models and use searchbox for select a few foreignkey

Tags: django, django-admin

I have these models;

```
class User(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class Project(models.Model):
    name       = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    start_date = models.DateTime()

class ProjectUser(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

Q1 : So i want to record project and projectUser from same page.

Q2 : if possible i want to use searchbox instate of combobox. Like Stackoverflow's tags (has search, select and cancel button to selected one)

Thanks from now.

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific regarding your questions here, as it's not clear what you're trying to do. It sounds like you want to use forms? If so, have a read through here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/ as it contains a lot of useful information.

Comment: OK, i'll look it